# Using WPF WebView To Access Localhost

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using **WebView** object from this [library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview) in my **WPF application**.
I can use it to connect to outside URL, but It seems that I can't use it for a site that resides in my LOCALHOST.

My Usecase is: I open google oauth2 site using **WebView** and plan to send oauth2 result to my localhost server.

Anybody ever try to use this **WebView** library from Microsoft Toolkit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be the built in security you're seeing. UWP apps are sandboxed and you need a workround to access localhost:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/dn640582(v=win.10)

You tried the webbrowser control?

Comment: WPF webbrowser control doesn't have new window request event to handle a link in page that request new window. I also need a way to execute js script which is not originally in the page. I'm doing a web scrapping.